# Saving customized movieclip as an image to local disk (diy generator)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

dropbox.com/s/77euop1luqjreos/FINAL.fla

Ok i just gave up with this already. I cant think of any way to save the image created by a user. Its hard to explain but please check out the fla file of my work. Basically its a diy generator. The only thing missing is a save function. Ive read filereference but its always in a document class. My code is in the timeline. Please help I'm really stuck.

edit: I got a download button that is working now!! But it only saves a small part of the movieclip: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX58R.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create images, you need to access the pixel data of the **MovieClip** object. The data can be obtained by rendering a **MovieClip** into a **BitmapData** object and using this data, you can write your own encoder to convert it to any image format you’d like. Writing such encoder is not a trivial task and requires understanding of the image format algorithm, or you can use pre-written libraries. You can download the **PNGEncoder** and **JPGEncoder** , which is part of [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/images/), an open source project library.

Using the **JPGEncoder**, we can convert **DisplayObject** into **ByteArray**, suitable for saving into file. If using the **JPGEncoder**, it’ll look like this:

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(quality);
//remember bitmapData here is just an example (do not try to compile this code without declare this particular variable)
var byteArray:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData);
```

With the **PNGEncoder**, it’ll look like this:

```
import com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder;
//remember bitmapData here is just an example (do not try to compile this code without declare this particular variable)
var byteArray:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bitmapData);
```

**Saving Into User’s Hard Drive**

Using the **FileReference**.save() function, we can prompt the user to save the file with the following call.

```
var fileReference:FileReference=new FileReference();
//in case of JPGEncoder
fileReference.save(byteArray, ".jpg");
```

With the two combined, here’s an example how to use:

```
//remember to import
import flash.net.FileReference;
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder; //or import com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

//where mc_canvas will be your MovieClip instance name
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc_canvas.width, mc_canvas.height);
bitmapData.draw(mc_canvas);  

var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(quality_slider.value);
var byteArray:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData);

//if you want to use PNGEncoder 
//var byteArray:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bitmapData);

var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileReference.save(byteArray, ".jpg");
```

Comment: Are those codes for timeline or document class? Cause i cant create a document class since im using timeline codes.

Comment: I'm sure that you can use for timeline as well. Just be sure that you will import all necessary classes (as cited on my answer) and download the class/package 'com.adobe.images...'

Comment: How do those installation packages work? Do i just install it and thats it? And how to i apply those codes on my timeline considering i have various keyframes that have different codes? Sorry im new to flash and i just taught myself how to do it.

Comment: I extremely recommend you to study more and look for informations about Classes, OOP, Design Patterns, find a good IDE (like Flash Builder, FDT, etc) and start to use a different approach. My answer was considering your need (generate an image from a movie clip and save it on the local disk). You could try to create a simple project and test it (isolated), to learn and understand how to use, then, make all necessary implementations on your current project.

Comment: I dont know. i want to study about it but i dont have much time. But i found this tutorial which is very easy to understand: http://www.webdesign.org/flash-swish/flash-tutorials/actionscript-3-jpeg-encoder-revealed-saving-images-from-flash.15525.html I just dont get the part on saving the file since when it reaches the frame where i put the filerefence code, it automatically opens a new browser window with the "get" url. And im not sure how to test if the moviclip was successfully converted to bitmap.

Comment: Its working now!!! The problem is, when it is saved, only a small part of the movieclip is seen!

Comment: Where exactly is the registration point parameter located in the code? Its not the new BitmapData(sqr.width, sqr.height); because from what i think it looks like, is just the width and height of the actual image. NOT where its gonna be saved.

Comment: When you create your movie clip. http://tinyurl.com/oe739mt
Be sure that you are passing the right width and height as well, on the BitmapData(sqr.width, sqr.height);

Comment: YES thank you!! Its working now. BUT now, the text and/or the dragged item is not included on the image! Just that one movieclip! Its supposed to look like this: http://i.imgur.com/azvEnVQ.png

Comment: I believe you will need yo analyse it and fix. Good luck! If possible, close the question accepting the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help. But do you think its possible? :( im starting to lose hope